# Get users who have access to circle

Tags: node.js, database, mongoose

I have following schema of users

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Name is required"],
      trim: true,
    },

    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Email is required"],
      validate: validator.isEmail,
      trim: true,
    },

  },

  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
module.exports = userSchema;
```

And I have following Schema of Circle

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const circlesSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    circleName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Circle name is required"],
      trim: true,
      unique: [true, "Circle name is already exists"],
    },

    blockedUsers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Users" }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
module.exports = circlesSchema;
```

In Circle schema there is field blockedUsers array, If users objectID is there in this array means user does not have access to this circle.
Now I want to get all users with their name who have access to the circle. I am new to Mongodb and looking for working mongo query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do two queries for that.

```js
const circle = await Circle.findOne({ circleName: 'My Circle' }).select('blockedUsers').lean();

const users = await User.find({ _id: { $nin: circle.blockedUsers } }).select('name');
```

You could also achieve that with a single aggregation pipeline, but the maintenance cost of that outweighs the benefit.

Also, I'd recommend reading [those blog posts](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) for schema design, your current schema design will possibly break for large numbers (hundreds of thousands) of blocked users.